# HDMI Video to RCA Audio

Tags: audio, analog, video, hdmi, rca

Some 20 years ago I created an audiovisual art installation, connecting RCA Video output from a TV set to a HiFi system's audio-in, just plain via cable, in order to "hear" the video signal. Also vice versa, sound from the HiFi system to the TV set, in order to "see" the audio signal.

I was wondering if the first part "hearing the video signal" would be somehow possible nowadays with a laptop having a HDMI output.

There are some HDMI to RCA cables out there. Would it work, to connect the RCA video output jack to the HiFi system's audio in?

Or is there more required? Maybe something like a converter first?

Or are there better solutions to achieve "hearing the video signal"?

Comment: you could definitely try that ... you would need a converter

Comment: HDMI to RCA is not just a cable, it must be a converter. Laptop would not output anything on HDMI, unless it finds that there is something plugged, and it is correctly detected as a video sink via the DDC interface. It also requires the TMDS video interface to be actively terminated to proper voltage. Even if you did manage to do all that, it would just be a stream of DC balanced encoded bits at 250 MBPS upwards, so there would not be any content that could be heard as audio. Perhaps convert to analog video first with a converter.

Comment: It would appear your previous project grossly abused these decoders to the point of non-meaning.  While you can maybe produce a similar video output with which to abuse an audio system, feeding audio to a video decoder is such utter nonsense that any result would be characteristic of the implementation and irreproducible.  Realistically, if you want to "see" sound or "hear" images, use software to create some sort of mapping which is *meaningful to you*.  Otherwise you're just rolling dice with the failure modes of abused technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signal on RCA Video output is called "composite video".

You can find "HDMI to composite video converters" online, with an HDMI input and a RCA output with composite video. If the product specification says "composite video output" it'll be the same signal that was on oldskool RCA video outputs, so that should work for your project.

Comment: But "composite video" doesn't carry the audio.

Comment: There exist products that can "extract" or take the audio from HDMI to analog RCA outputs. Sometimes called A/V receivers.

Comment: According to the question, OP wants to listen to composite video for an art project... Hey, why not?

Comment: I can imagine it in a way that the buzzing changes according to video - could be intetesting if analog video  camera is used so that the art exhibit visitor can take part and affect the sound by moving in front of the camera. Could be even more interesting than feeding SPDIF output into CRT composite input, which just displays grey wide pixels.

Comment: @Justme - exactly, only I do not use a videocam for my audiovisual installation but a three.js generated interactive 3d lineart projection (user can rotate/zoom by moving around) - fed into audioin with a synth in-between in order to create drone sounds